# target child id el by knowing the parent class

Tags: css

I have a css class that has a couple of children and I know that the child ellement that I want to target has an id that ends with '`inner-Ct`. I don't want to assign it my unique id because it will be used in many places.

```
<div class="totalSummary">
    <div>
        <div id = "form-1406-innerCt"></div> //<---- this is the one I want to target
          ...
    <div>
</div>
```

It's there a way to do this using css?

Comment: Please use proper spelling and grammar in your posts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
.totalSummary div[id$="innerCT"] {
    color: gold;  /* The $ indicates a string that an attribute
                     value ends with, in this case "innerCt" */
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xgRk7/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `$` attribute selector to match the end of the ID like:

```
.totalSummary div[id$="innerCt"] {
    background: red;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JUt9r/1)**

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors

> [att$=val] Represents an element with the att attribute whose value
>   ends with the suffix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the
>   selector does not represent anything.

Comment: Don't forget the `div.totalSummary ` beforehand - if I understand the OP correctly it needs to be inside a div with that class.